# Stack level too deep when trying to update_attributes which haven't changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

This rather convoluted form works OK when there are params with "books" changes, but throws an impossible-to-debug `stack level too deep` error when params are submitted with no changes in the data. Any thoughts? I've commented out every validation and callback in all the models to no avail.

View:

```
  = semantic_form_for(@work, :method => :put, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f|
       # some code
            = f.semantic_fields_for(:workcontacts, wc) do |ff|           
            #...
    = f.semantic_fields_for(:books, @book) do |gg|              
      = gg.input :contributor_statement, :input_html => {:class => 'wysihtml5'}
```

Controller:

```
  def update
    @work     = Work.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|        
        begin
          if @work.update_attributes(params[:work])
          flash[:success] = "#{@work.title} #{t(:global_save)}"
          format.html { redirect_to :back, :work => @work.id }
          format.json { respond_with_bip(@work) }
        else
          format.html { 
            redirect_to :back, :work => @work.id
            flash[:failure] = "#{@work.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
          }
          format.json { respond_with_bip(@work) }
        end
        rescue SystemStackError
          puts $!
          puts caller[0..100]
        end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this, because it won't help a soul, but posting the solution for completeness.

A Work

```
has_many :books              , :inverse_of => :work
```

A Book

```
  belongs_to :work         , :inverse_of => :books, :touch => :child_updated_at, counter_cache: true
```

In the Book model I had

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work
```

Which is the culprit.

Comment: Well, I thought I found the problem and this validated it for me, so it did help.  I had flipped two models from has_one/belongs_to to the inverse and had not removed the accepts_nested_attributes_for in the belongs_to which gave me the loop.

Comment: Almost four years to the day! Some problems are timeless.

Answer (score 1):

`Stack Level Too Deep` basically means you have an `infinite` (`recursive`) `loop` somewhere in your application

--

**Fix**

Your code seems somewhat unconventional, so I've refactorered it for you:

```
  def update
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|        
          if @work.update(work_params)
              format.html {
                  flash[:success] = "#{@work.title} #{t(:global_save)}"
                  redirect_to :back, :work => @work.id
              }
              format.json { respond_with_bip(@work) }
          else
              format.html { 
                 redirect_to :back, :work => @work.id
                 flash[:failure] = "#{@work.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}"
               }
               format.json { respond_with_bip(@work) }
           end
      end
  end

  private

  def work_params
      params.require(:work).permit(:x, :y, :z)
  end
```

It looks to me like this code should work for you. However, I would suggest you post your `model` code for the `Work` model - as you'd typically have `stack level too deep` if you're using an [`after_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback which saves again (hence going round in circles)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said that I'm on Rails 3, which sadly doesn't have the `update` method (or strong params). Thanks so much though -- I'll come back to this when I upgrade.